# jquery get value of element

Tags: jquery, html

this is my code, which create 10 form elements with a button "Delete"

```
<?php

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) { ?>
<form action="xxx" method="post">
   <div>
      <a class="button">Delete</a>
   </div>

    <input type="hidden" name="MyID" value="<? echo $i; ?>" />
</form>
<? } ?>
```

I need to know, which button was clicked to get the value of "MyID"
I knw this jquery onclick function:

```
$( ".button" ).click(function() {
  alert("Button clicked);
  $(".MyID").val(); // THE ID
});
```

But the input field with "MyID" exists 10 times.
The code cant work like this.
How can I realize it?

Comment: One method is to select the hidden `<input>` *relative to* whichever `<a>` was clicked. You might find information about [Traversal](http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/traversing-manipulating) helpful, specifically [Finding elements relative to a selection](http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/traversing-manipulating#finding-elements-relative-to-a-selection). Also see [Tree Traversal](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it using the following code

```js
$( ".button" ).click(function() {
   alert($(this).closest('form').find('input[name$="MyID"]').val()); // THE ID
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="xxx" method="post">
   <div>
      <a class="button">Delete</a>
   </div>

    <input type="hidden" name="MyID" value="1" />
</form>
<form action="xxx" method="post">
   <div>
      <a class="button">Delete</a>
   </div>

    <input type="hidden" name="MyID" value="2" />
</form>
<form action="xxx" method="post">
   <div>
      <a class="button">Delete</a>
   </div>

    <input type="hidden" name="MyID" value="3" />
</form>
<form action="xxx" method="post">
   <div>
      <a class="button">Delete</a>
   </div>

    <input type="hidden" name="MyID" value="4" />
</form>
<form action="xxx" method="post">
   <div>
      <a class="button">Delete</a>
   </div>

    <input type="hidden" name="MyID" value="5" />
</form>
<form action="xxx" method="post">
   <div>
      <a class="button">Delete</a>
   </div>

    <input type="hidden" name="MyID" value="6" />
</form>
<form action="xxx" method="post">
   <div>
      <a class="button">Delete</a>
   </div>

    <input type="hidden" name="MyID" value="7" />
</form>
<form action="xxx" method="post">
   <div>
      <a class="button">Delete</a>
   </div>

    <input type="hidden" name="MyID" value="8" />
</form>
<form action="xxx" method="post">
   <div>
      <a class="button">Delete</a>
   </div>

    <input type="hidden" name="MyID" value="9" />
</form>
<form action="xxx" method="post">
   <div>
      <a class="button">Delete</a>
   </div>

    <input type="hidden" name="MyID" value="10" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a class="button" data-id="<? echo $i; ?>">Delete</a>
```

Then access it with the `data('id')` method.